# How to group together rows if the column value exists in a specified list, using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have list as such, named "list_of_words":

```
['Haha', 'No', 'Why']
```

and a dataframe as such:

```
        Letter     Count        
1       Yes        2
2       Haha       3
3       Why        4
4       No         9
5       Teeth      8
```

I want to create a resulting dataframe as such, where any rows where the value in column 'Letter' exists in "list_of_words" are grouped together and renamed as "Other":

```
        Letter     Count        
1       Yes        2
2       Other      16
5       Teeth      8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIrst idea is use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) before aggregate `sum`, but then all duplicated are aggregated:

```
list_of_words = ['Haha', 'No', 'Why']

df['Letter'] = df['Letter'].replace(list_of_words, 'Other')
df = df.groupby('Letter', as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
  Letter  Count
0  Other     16
1  Teeth      8
2    Yes      2
```

If need aggregate only words from `list_of_words`:

```
list_of_words = ['Haha', 'No', 'Why']

m = df['Letter'].isin(list_of_words)

df = pd.concat([df[~m], 
                df[m].assign(Letter = 'Other').groupby('Letter', as_index=False).sum()], 
                ignore_index=True)
print (df)
  Letter  Count
0    Yes      2
1  Teeth      8
2  Other     16
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
df.groupby(['Letter']).sum()
```