# Pandas subtotal similar to Excel

Tags: python, pandas, subtotal

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
     A   B      C
0    21  Blue   100 
1    33  Yellow 100 
2    17  White  250 
3    A2  Grey   40
4    65  Green  500 
5    33  Red    80 
6    17  Purple -50
7    A2  Orange 600
```

Column B is basically irrelevant information IRT the code itself but still needs to be included in the output.
I have sorted the dataframe by column A and gotten around the issue that col A has contains both int and str:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str)
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['A'])
```

So now `df_sorted` looks like this:

```
     A   B      C
2    17  White  250
6    17  Purple -50
0    21  Blue   100
1    33  Yellow 100
5    33  Red    80
4    65  Green  500
3    A2  Grey   40
7    A2  Orange 600
```

My question is: How can I then make subtotals for each change in col A by summarizing col C similar to Excel's subtotal function?
The final output of the dataframe should look like this:

```
     A        B      C
2    17       White  250
6    17       Purple -50
     Subtotal        200  
0    21       Blue   100
     Subtotal        100
1    33       Yellow 100
5    33       Red    80
     Subtotal        180
4    65       Green  500
     Subtotal        500
3    A2       Grey   40
7    A2       Orange 600
     Subtotal        640
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group together rows if the column value exists in a specified list, using Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66345780/how-to-group-together-rows-if-the-column-value-exists-in-a-specified-list-using)

Comment: getting subtotals is easy enough: `df.groupby('A')['C'].sum()` but merging it into the original df is not so easy, is that what you want ultimately?

Comment: @balandongiv not quite unfortunately because I need to create subtotals for each change in col A to the df

Comment: @piterbarg yes ultimately the subtotals should be included in the original df, or could be in a new one as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can `concat` your original df and the groupby subtotal.

```
df1 =  pd.concat([df,
             df.groupby(['A'],as_index=False)['C'].sum()]).sort_values('A')

df1.loc[df1['B'].isnull(), 'A'] = 'Subtotal'

print(df1.fillna(''))

          A       B    C
2        17   White  250
6        17  Purple  -50
0  Subtotal          200
0        21    Blue  100
1  Subtotal          100
1        33  Yellow  100
5        33     Red   80
2  Subtotal          180
4        65   Green  500
3  Subtotal          500
3        A2    Grey   40
7        A2  Orange  600
4  Subtotal          640
```

Comment: In the end you can also do a `df1.reset_index(drop=True)` so that you don't have random indexes.

Comment: can you please explain me this? 
df1.loc[df1['B'].isnull(), 'A'] = 'Subtotal'