# Adding level 2 index as a sum of other indexes with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({('group', ''): {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'A',
  6: 'A',
  7: 'A',
  8: 'A',
  9: 'B',
  10: 'B',
  11: 'B',
  12: 'B',
  13: 'B',
  14: 'B',
  15: 'B',
  16: 'B',
  17: 'B',
  18: 'all',
  19: 'all'},
 ('category', ''): {0: 'Amazon',
  1: 'Apple',
  2: 'Facebook',
  3: 'Google',
  4: 'Netflix',
  5: 'Tesla',
  6: 'Total',
  7: 'Uber',
  8: 'total',
  9: 'Amazon',
  10: 'Apple',
  11: 'Facebook',
  12: 'Google',
  13: 'Netflix',
  14: 'Tesla',
  15: 'Total',
  16: 'Uber',
  17: 'total',
  18: 'Total',
  19: 'total'},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'), 'last_sales'): {0: 195.0,
  1: 61.0,
  2: 106.0,
  3: 61.0,
  4: 37.0,
  5: 13.0,
  6: 954.0,
  7: 4.0,
  8: 477.0,
  9: 50.0,
  10: 50.0,
  11: 75.0,
  12: 43.0,
  13: 17.0,
  14: 14.0,
  15: 504.0,
  16: 3.0,
  17: 252.0,
  18: 2916.0,
  19: 2916.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'), 'sales'): {0: 1268.85,
  1: 18274.385000000002,
  2: 19722.65,
  3: 55547.255,
  4: 15323.800000000001,
  5: 1688.6749999999997,
  6: 227463.23,
  7: 1906.0,
  8: 113731.615,
  9: 3219.6499999999996,
  10: 15852.060000000001,
  11: 17743.7,
  12: 37795.15,
  13: 5918.5,
  14: 1708.75,
  15: 166349.64,
  16: 937.01,
  17: 83174.82,
  18: 787625.7400000001,
  19: 787625.7400000001},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'), 'difference'): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 0.0,
  19: 0.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-07-06 00:00:00'), 'last_sales'): {0: 26.0,
  1: 39.0,
  2: 79.0,
  3: 49.0,
  4: 10.0,
  5: 10.0,
  6: 436.0,
  7: 5.0,
  8: 218.0,
  9: 89.0,
  10: 34.0,
  11: 133.0,
  12: 66.0,
  13: 21.0,
  14: 20.0,
  15: 732.0,
  16: 3.0,
  17: 366.0,
  18: 2336.0,
  19: 2336.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-07-06 00:00:00'), 'sales'): {0: 3978.15,
  1: 12138.96,
  2: 19084.175,
  3: 40033.46000000001,
  4: 4280.15,
  5: 1495.1,
  6: 165548.29,
  7: 1764.15,
  8: 82774.145,
  9: 8314.92,
  10: 12776.649999999996,
  11: 28048.075,
  12: 55104.21000000002,
  13: 6962.844999999999,
  14: 3053.2000000000003,
  15: 231049.11000000002,
  16: 1264.655,
  17: 115524.55500000001,
  18: 793194.8000000002,
  19: 793194.8000000002},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-07-06 00:00:00'), 'difference'): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 0.0,
  19: 0.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'last_sales'): {0: 96.0,
  1: 56.0,
  2: 106.0,
  3: 44.0,
  4: 34.0,
  5: 13.0,
  6: 716.0,
  7: 9.0,
  8: 358.0,
  9: 101.0,
  10: 22.0,
  11: 120.0,
  12: 40.0,
  13: 13.0,
  14: 8.0,
  15: 610.0,
  16: 1.0,
  17: 305.0,
  18: 2652.0,
  19: 2652.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'sales'): {0: 5194.95,
  1: 19102.219999999994,
  2: 22796.420000000002,
  3: 30853.115,
  4: 11461.25,
  5: 992.6,
  6: 188143.41,
  7: 3671.15,
  8: 94071.705,
  9: 6022.299999999998,
  10: 7373.6,
  11: 33514.0,
  12: 35943.45,
  13: 4749.000000000001,
  14: 902.01,
  15: 177707.32,
  16: 349.3,
  17: 88853.66,
  18: 731701.46,
  19: 731701.46},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'difference'): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 0.0,
  19: 0.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-07 00:00:00'), 'last_sales'): {0: 45.0,
  1: 47.0,
  2: 87.0,
  3: 45.0,
  4: 13.0,
  5: 8.0,
  6: 494.0,
  7: 2.0,
  8: 247.0,
  9: 81.0,
  10: 36.0,
  11: 143.0,
  12: 56.0,
  13: 9.0,
  14: 9.0,
  15: 670.0,
  16: 1.0,
  17: 335.0,
  18: 2328.0,
  19: 2328.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-07 00:00:00'), 'sales'): {0: 7556.414999999998,
  1: 14985.05,
  2: 16790.899999999998,
  3: 36202.729999999996,
  4: 4024.97,
  5: 1034.45,
  6: 163960.32999999996,
  7: 1385.65,
  8: 81980.16499999998,
  9: 5600.544999999999,
  10: 11209.92,
  11: 32832.61,
  12: 42137.44500000001,
  13: 3885.1499999999996,
  14: 1191.5,
  15: 194912.34000000003,
  16: 599.0,
  17: 97456.17000000001,
  18: 717745.3400000001,
  19: 717745.3400000001},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-07 00:00:00'), 'difference'): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 0.0,
  19: 0.0}}).set_index(['group','category'])
```

I am trying to create a level 2 `index` called `combined` which would be the sum of `sales & last_sales` of all `categories` except for `Facebook` and `total` / `Total`.
So that the `df` would look like this:

[image]

I tried doing it with `.loc` but with no success:

```
s = df_out.stack(0)

s['combined'] = 0
s.loc[(slice(None),[x for x in s.loc[(slice(None),:) if x != 'Facebook']].sum()
```

Comment: Do you want to exclude `Total` and `total` categories in `level=1`?

Comment: Yes, will update my question formulation.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66350904/pandas-subtotal-similar-to-excel/66351043#66351043) answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution

- Drop `all` in `level=0`, similarly `drop` the other unwanted level values in `level=1`
- Calculate the `sum` on `level=0` to aggregate the frame
- Create `Multindex` to add the additional level `combined` in aggregated frame
- Append and sort the index to maintain the order

```
s = df.drop('all').drop(['Facebook', 'total', 'Total'], level=1).sum(level=0)
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([s.index, ['combined']])
df_out = df.append(s).sort_index()
```

##### Result

```
                        2020-06-29 00:00:00                        2020-07-06 00:00:00                        2021-06-28 00:00:00                        2021-07-07 00:00:00                       
                        last_sales       sales difference          last_sales       sales difference          last_sales       sales difference          last_sales       sales difference
group category                                                                                                                                                                            
A     Amazon                 195.0    1268.850        0.0                26.0    3978.150        0.0                96.0    5194.950        0.0                45.0    7556.415        0.0
      Apple                   61.0   18274.385        0.0                39.0   12138.960        0.0                56.0   19102.220        0.0                47.0   14985.050        0.0
      Facebook               106.0   19722.650        0.0                79.0   19084.175        0.0               106.0   22796.420        0.0                87.0   16790.900        0.0
      Google                  61.0   55547.255        0.0                49.0   40033.460        0.0                44.0   30853.115        0.0                45.0   36202.730        0.0
      Netflix                 37.0   15323.800        0.0                10.0    4280.150        0.0                34.0   11461.250        0.0                13.0    4024.970        0.0
      Tesla                   13.0    1688.675        0.0                10.0    1495.100        0.0                13.0     992.600        0.0                 8.0    1034.450        0.0
      Total                  954.0  227463.230        0.0               436.0  165548.290        0.0               716.0  188143.410        0.0               494.0  163960.330        0.0
      Uber                     4.0    1906.000        0.0                 5.0    1764.150        0.0                 9.0    3671.150        0.0                 2.0    1385.650        0.0
      combined               371.0   94008.965        0.0               139.0   63689.970        0.0               252.0   71275.285        0.0               160.0   65189.265        0.0
      total                  477.0  113731.615        0.0               218.0   82774.145        0.0               358.0   94071.705        0.0               247.0   81980.165        0.0
B     Amazon                  50.0    3219.650        0.0                89.0    8314.920        0.0               101.0    6022.300        0.0                81.0    5600.545        0.0
      Apple                   50.0   15852.060        0.0                34.0   12776.650        0.0                22.0    7373.600        0.0                36.0   11209.920        0.0
      Facebook                75.0   17743.700        0.0               133.0   28048.075        0.0               120.0   33514.000        0.0               143.0   32832.610        0.0
      Google                  43.0   37795.150        0.0                66.0   55104.210        0.0                40.0   35943.450        0.0                56.0   42137.445        0.0
      Netflix                 17.0    5918.500        0.0                21.0    6962.845        0.0                13.0    4749.000        0.0                 9.0    3885.150        0.0
      Tesla                   14.0    1708.750        0.0                20.0    3053.200        0.0                 8.0     902.010        0.0                 9.0    1191.500        0.0
      Total                  504.0  166349.640        0.0               732.0  231049.110        0.0               610.0  177707.320        0.0               670.0  194912.340        0.0
      Uber                     3.0     937.010        0.0                 3.0    1264.655        0.0                 1.0     349.300        0.0                 1.0     599.000        0.0
      combined               177.0   65431.120        0.0               233.0   87476.480        0.0               185.0   55339.660        0.0               192.0   64623.560        0.0
      total                  252.0   83174.820        0.0               366.0  115524.555        0.0               305.0   88853.660        0.0               335.0   97456.170        0.0
all   Total                 2916.0  787625.740        0.0              2336.0  793194.800        0.0              2652.0  731701.460        0.0              2328.0  717745.340        0.0
      total                 2916.0  787625.740        0.0              2336.0  793194.800        0.0              2652.0  731701.460        0.0              2328.0  717745.340        0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group on level 0, and `concat` the sum per group if the `name` is not "all", while adding indexes. Then combine this output with the original data and `sort_index` by `level=0`:

```
pd.concat([df,
           pd.concat({(name, 'combined'): d.drop(['Facebook', 'total', 'Total'], level=1).sum()
                      for name,d in df.groupby(level=0) if name != 'all'}, axis=1).T
          ]).sort_index(level=0)
```

output:

```
               2020-06-29 00:00:00                        2020-07-06 00:00:00                        2021-06-28 00:00:00                        2021-07-07 00:00:00                       
                        last_sales       sales difference          last_sales       sales difference          last_sales       sales difference          last_sales       sales difference
group category                                                                                                                                                                            
A     Amazon                 195.0    1268.850        0.0                26.0    3978.150        0.0                96.0    5194.950        0.0                45.0    7556.415        0.0
      Apple                   61.0   18274.385        0.0                39.0   12138.960        0.0                56.0   19102.220        0.0                47.0   14985.050        0.0
      Facebook               106.0   19722.650        0.0                79.0   19084.175        0.0               106.0   22796.420        0.0                87.0   16790.900        0.0
      Google                  61.0   55547.255        0.0                49.0   40033.460        0.0                44.0   30853.115        0.0                45.0   36202.730        0.0
      Netflix                 37.0   15323.800        0.0                10.0    4280.150        0.0                34.0   11461.250        0.0                13.0    4024.970        0.0
      Tesla                   13.0    1688.675        0.0                10.0    1495.100        0.0                13.0     992.600        0.0                 8.0    1034.450        0.0
      Total                  954.0  227463.230        0.0               436.0  165548.290        0.0               716.0  188143.410        0.0               494.0  163960.330        0.0
      Uber                     4.0    1906.000        0.0                 5.0    1764.150        0.0                 9.0    3671.150        0.0                 2.0    1385.650        0.0
      combined               371.0   94008.965        0.0               139.0   63689.970        0.0               252.0   71275.285        0.0               160.0   65189.265        0.0
      total                  477.0  113731.615        0.0               218.0   82774.145        0.0               358.0   94071.705        0.0               247.0   81980.165        0.0
B     Amazon                  50.0    3219.650        0.0                89.0    8314.920        0.0               101.0    6022.300        0.0                81.0    5600.545        0.0
      Apple                   50.0   15852.060        0.0                34.0   12776.650        0.0                22.0    7373.600        0.0                36.0   11209.920        0.0
      Facebook                75.0   17743.700        0.0               133.0   28048.075        0.0               120.0   33514.000        0.0               143.0   32832.610        0.0
      Google                  43.0   37795.150        0.0                66.0   55104.210        0.0                40.0   35943.450        0.0                56.0   42137.445        0.0
      Netflix                 17.0    5918.500        0.0                21.0    6962.845        0.0                13.0    4749.000        0.0                 9.0    3885.150        0.0
      Tesla                   14.0    1708.750        0.0                20.0    3053.200        0.0                 8.0     902.010        0.0                 9.0    1191.500        0.0
      Total                  504.0  166349.640        0.0               732.0  231049.110        0.0               610.0  177707.320        0.0               670.0  194912.340        0.0
      Uber                     3.0     937.010        0.0                 3.0    1264.655        0.0                 1.0     349.300        0.0                 1.0     599.000        0.0
      combined               177.0   65431.120        0.0               233.0   87476.480        0.0               185.0   55339.660        0.0               192.0   64623.560        0.0
      total                  252.0   83174.820        0.0               366.0  115524.555        0.0               305.0   88853.660        0.0               335.0   97456.170        0.0
all   Total                 2916.0  787625.740        0.0              2336.0  793194.800        0.0              2652.0  731701.460        0.0              2328.0  717745.340        0.0
      total                 2916.0  787625.740        0.0              2336.0  793194.800        0.0              2652.0  731701.460        0.0              2328.0  717745.340        0.0
```