# Adding multiindex to pandas dataframe which is the sum of same dataframe's values

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({('group', ''): {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'A',
  6: 'A',
  7: 'A',
  8: 'A',
  9: 'B',
  10: 'B',
  11: 'B',
  12: 'B',
  13: 'B',
  14: 'B',
  15: 'B',
  16: 'B',
  17: 'B',
  18: 'all',
  19: 'all'},
 ('category', ''): {0: 'Amazon',
  1: 'Apple',
  2: 'Facebook',
  3: 'Google',
  4: 'Netflix',
  5: 'Tesla',
  6: 'Total',
  7: 'Uber',
  8: 'total',
  9: 'Amazon',
  10: 'Apple',
  11: 'Facebook',
  12: 'Google',
  13: 'Netflix',
  14: 'Tesla',
  15: 'Total',
  16: 'Uber',
  17: 'total',
  18: 'Total',
  19: 'total'},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'), 'last_sales'): {0: 195.0,
  1: 61.0,
  2: 106.0,
  3: 61.0,
  4: 37.0,
  5: 13.0,
  6: 954.0,
  7: 4.0,
  8: 477.0,
  9: 50.0,
  10: 50.0,
  11: 75.0,
  12: 43.0,
  13: 17.0,
  14: 14.0,
  15: 504.0,
  16: 3.0,
  17: 252.0,
  18: 2916.0,
  19: 2916.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'), 'sales'): {0: 1268.85,
  1: 18274.385000000002,
  2: 19722.65,
  3: 55547.255,
  4: 15323.800000000001,
  5: 1688.6749999999997,
  6: 227463.23,
  7: 1906.0,
  8: 113731.615,
  9: 3219.6499999999996,
  10: 15852.060000000001,
  11: 17743.7,
  12: 37795.15,
  13: 5918.5,
  14: 1708.75,
  15: 166349.64,
  16: 937.01,
  17: 83174.82,
  18: 787625.7400000001,
  19: 787625.7400000001},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'), 'difference'): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 0.0,
  19: 0.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-07-06 00:00:00'), 'last_sales'): {0: 26.0,
  1: 39.0,
  2: 79.0,
  3: 49.0,
  4: 10.0,
  5: 10.0,
  6: 436.0,
  7: 5.0,
  8: 218.0,
  9: 89.0,
  10: 34.0,
  11: 133.0,
  12: 66.0,
  13: 21.0,
  14: 20.0,
  15: 732.0,
  16: 3.0,
  17: 366.0,
  18: 2336.0,
  19: 2336.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-07-06 00:00:00'), 'sales'): {0: 3978.15,
  1: 12138.96,
  2: 19084.175,
  3: 40033.46000000001,
  4: 4280.15,
  5: 1495.1,
  6: 165548.29,
  7: 1764.15,
  8: 82774.145,
  9: 8314.92,
  10: 12776.649999999996,
  11: 28048.075,
  12: 55104.21000000002,
  13: 6962.844999999999,
  14: 3053.2000000000003,
  15: 231049.11000000002,
  16: 1264.655,
  17: 115524.55500000001,
  18: 793194.8000000002,
  19: 793194.8000000002},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-07-06 00:00:00'), 'difference'): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 0.0,
  19: 0.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'last_sales'): {0: 96.0,
  1: 56.0,
  2: 106.0,
  3: 44.0,
  4: 34.0,
  5: 13.0,
  6: 716.0,
  7: 9.0,
  8: 358.0,
  9: 101.0,
  10: 22.0,
  11: 120.0,
  12: 40.0,
  13: 13.0,
  14: 8.0,
  15: 610.0,
  16: 1.0,
  17: 305.0,
  18: 2652.0,
  19: 2652.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'sales'): {0: 5194.95,
  1: 19102.219999999994,
  2: 22796.420000000002,
  3: 30853.115,
  4: 11461.25,
  5: 992.6,
  6: 188143.41,
  7: 3671.15,
  8: 94071.705,
  9: 6022.299999999998,
  10: 7373.6,
  11: 33514.0,
  12: 35943.45,
  13: 4749.000000000001,
  14: 902.01,
  15: 177707.32,
  16: 349.3,
  17: 88853.66,
  18: 731701.46,
  19: 731701.46},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'difference'): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 0.0,
  19: 0.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-07 00:00:00'), 'last_sales'): {0: 45.0,
  1: 47.0,
  2: 87.0,
  3: 45.0,
  4: 13.0,
  5: 8.0,
  6: 494.0,
  7: 2.0,
  8: 247.0,
  9: 81.0,
  10: 36.0,
  11: 143.0,
  12: 56.0,
  13: 9.0,
  14: 9.0,
  15: 670.0,
  16: 1.0,
  17: 335.0,
  18: 2328.0,
  19: 2328.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-07 00:00:00'), 'sales'): {0: 7556.414999999998,
  1: 14985.05,
  2: 16790.899999999998,
  3: 36202.729999999996,
  4: 4024.97,
  5: 1034.45,
  6: 163960.32999999996,
  7: 1385.65,
  8: 81980.16499999998,
  9: 5600.544999999999,
  10: 11209.92,
  11: 32832.61,
  12: 42137.44500000001,
  13: 3885.1499999999996,
  14: 1191.5,
  15: 194912.34000000003,
  16: 599.0,
  17: 97456.17000000001,
  18: 717745.3400000001,
  19: 717745.3400000001},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-07 00:00:00'), 'difference'): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 0.0,
  17: 0.0,
  18: 0.0,
  19: 0.0}}).set_index(['group','category'])
```

I am trying to create a level `1` index `combined` and level `2` index would be the names of the current index level `2` `category` but without the `total`

```
'Amazon',
'Apple',
'Facebook',
'Google',
'Netflix',
'Tesla',
'Uber'
```

Which would be the sum of all level `1` indexes `group` per `category`, excluding the `all` `group` at level `1` index of column `sales`. Basically get a total of all `groups` excluding `all`,  `sum` per `category`.

[image]

Would it also be possible to be able to write the `group` names for `combined` index to take in to account, so that I would be able to sum the `combined` `categories` for selected `groups` rather than every `group` excluding `all`?

I tried:

```
c = df.reset_index()
c[(c.group.isin(['A','B']))& (c.category.isin(['Amazon','Apple','Facebook', 'Google', 'Netflix', 'Tesla', 'Uber']))].loc[:,(slice(None),'sales')].sum()
```

But then I realised this is not grouped per `category` so I am not sure how to continue.

Example of expected output ( data is not consistent ):

```
                        2020-06-29 00:00:00 
                        last_sales  sales       difference  
group       category                                                
combined    Amazon      195.000     1,268.850   0.000   
            Apple       61.000      18,274.385  0.000   
            Facebook    106.000     19,722.650  0.000   
            Google      61.000      55,547.255  0.000   
            Netflix     37.000      15,323.800  0.000   
            Tesla       13.000      1,688.675   0.000   
            Uber        4.000       1,906.000   0.000   
A           Amazon      50.000      3,219.650   0.000   
            Apple       50.000      15,852.060  0.000   
            Facebook    75.000      17,743.700  0.000   
            Google      43.000      37,795.150  0.000   
            Netflix     17.000      5,918.500   0.000   
            Tesla       14.000      1,708.750   0.000   
            Total       504.000     166,349.640 0.000   
            Uber        3.000       937.010     0.000   
            total       252.000     83,174.820  0.000   
B           Amazon      50.000      3,219.650   0.000   
            Apple       50.000      15,852.060  0.000   
            Facebook    75.000      17,743.700  0.000   
            Google      43.000      37,795.150  0.000   
            Netflix     17.000      5,918.500   0.000   
            Tesla       14.000      1,708.750   0.000   
            Total       504.000     166,349.640 0.000   
            Uber        3.000       937.010     0.000   
            total       252.000     83,174.820  0.000   
all         Total       2,916.000   787,625.740 0.000   
            total       2,916.000   787,625.740 0.000
```

Comment: This seems like a variation of a question you already asked: [Adding level 2 index as a sum of other indexes with a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68483090/adding-level-2-index-as-a-sum-of-other-indexes-with-a-condition)

Comment: It is similar, but this does not add a level `1` index, only adds level `2` index instead. I need a level `1` index and preserve the current level `2` indexes.

Comment: where is your expected output?

Comment: @Umar.H, added an example expected output.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis Why is `total` present in the expected output?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, removed it, thank you, that is added in further calculations.

Comment: the sums don't really make sense, how does 50 + 50 = 195?

Comment: That's an example, data is not consistent.

Comment: I have to admit that is very frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reiterating over the idea from my [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68483090/adding-level-2-index-as-a-sum-of-other-indexes-with-a-condition), we can solve this problem in the following way

```
s = df.loc[['A', 'B']].drop(['total', 'Total'], level=1).sum(level=1)
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['combined'], s.index])
df_out = s.append(df)
```

Result

```
print(df_out)
                           2020-06-29 00:00:00                        2020-07-06 00:00:00                        2021-06-28 00:00:00                        2021-07-07 00:00:00                       
                           last_sales       sales difference          last_sales       sales difference          last_sales       sales difference          last_sales       sales difference
         category                                                                                                                                                                            
combined Amazon                 245.0    4488.500        0.0               115.0   12293.070        0.0               197.0   11217.250        0.0               126.0   13156.960        0.0
         Apple                  111.0   34126.445        0.0                73.0   24915.610        0.0                78.0   26475.820        0.0                83.0   26194.970        0.0
         Facebook               181.0   37466.350        0.0               212.0   47132.250        0.0               226.0   56310.420        0.0               230.0   49623.510        0.0
         Google                 104.0   93342.405        0.0               115.0   95137.670        0.0                84.0   66796.565        0.0               101.0   78340.175        0.0
         Netflix                 54.0   21242.300        0.0                31.0   11242.995        0.0                47.0   16210.250        0.0                22.0    7910.120        0.0
         Tesla                   27.0    3397.425        0.0                30.0    4548.300        0.0                21.0    1894.610        0.0                17.0    2225.950        0.0
         Uber                     7.0    2843.010        0.0                 8.0    3028.805        0.0                10.0    4020.450        0.0                 3.0    1984.650        0.0
A        Amazon                 195.0    1268.850        0.0                26.0    3978.150        0.0                96.0    5194.950        0.0                45.0    7556.415        0.0
         Apple                   61.0   18274.385        0.0                39.0   12138.960        0.0                56.0   19102.220        0.0                47.0   14985.050        0.0
         Facebook               106.0   19722.650        0.0                79.0   19084.175        0.0               106.0   22796.420        0.0                87.0   16790.900        0.0
         Google                  61.0   55547.255        0.0                49.0   40033.460        0.0                44.0   30853.115        0.0                45.0   36202.730        0.0
         Netflix                 37.0   15323.800        0.0                10.0    4280.150        0.0                34.0   11461.250        0.0                13.0    4024.970        0.0
         Tesla                   13.0    1688.675        0.0                10.0    1495.100        0.0                13.0     992.600        0.0                 8.0    1034.450        0.0
         Total                  954.0  227463.230        0.0               436.0  165548.290        0.0               716.0  188143.410        0.0               494.0  163960.330        0.0
         Uber                     4.0    1906.000        0.0                 5.0    1764.150        0.0                 9.0    3671.150        0.0                 2.0    1385.650        0.0
         total                  477.0  113731.615        0.0               218.0   82774.145        0.0               358.0   94071.705        0.0               247.0   81980.165        0.0
B        Amazon                  50.0    3219.650        0.0                89.0    8314.920        0.0               101.0    6022.300        0.0                81.0    5600.545        0.0
         Apple                   50.0   15852.060        0.0                34.0   12776.650        0.0                22.0    7373.600        0.0                36.0   11209.920        0.0
         Facebook                75.0   17743.700        0.0               133.0   28048.075        0.0               120.0   33514.000        0.0               143.0   32832.610        0.0
         Google                  43.0   37795.150        0.0                66.0   55104.210        0.0                40.0   35943.450        0.0                56.0   42137.445        0.0
         Netflix                 17.0    5918.500        0.0                21.0    6962.845        0.0                13.0    4749.000        0.0                 9.0    3885.150        0.0
         Tesla                   14.0    1708.750        0.0                20.0    3053.200        0.0                 8.0     902.010        0.0                 9.0    1191.500        0.0
         Total                  504.0  166349.640        0.0               732.0  231049.110        0.0               610.0  177707.320        0.0               670.0  194912.340        0.0
         Uber                     3.0     937.010        0.0                 3.0    1264.655        0.0                 1.0     349.300        0.0                 1.0     599.000        0.0
         total                  252.0   83174.820        0.0               366.0  115524.555        0.0               305.0   88853.660        0.0               335.0   97456.170        0.0
all      Total                 2916.0  787625.740        0.0              2336.0  793194.800        0.0              2652.0  731701.460        0.0              2328.0  717745.340        0.0
         total                 2916.0  787625.740        0.0              2336.0  793194.800        0.0              2652.0  731701.460        0.0              2328.0  717745.340        0.0
```